# How can i get a clean script embedded in an html page with python standard library

Tags: python, html, json, python-3.x, urllib

I'm trying to backup a code of mine from sololearn site. I could copy/paste it of course, but because i would like to repeat it for other codes, and also for learning purpose, i'd like to do it with a python code, and only using the standard library if possible.

I present here the more basic try. I also have been struggling with HTMLParser,  html.entities, xml.etree, i've tried to decode the response as "utf-8", to pass it through html.unescape(). The result is always dirty.
this kind of dirty: \u003c!DOCTYPE html\u003e\r\n\u003chtml\u003e\r\n\u003c!--\r\
sometimes less, but never clean

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

url = "https://code.sololearn.com/************/#"
with urlopen(url) as response:
    page = str(response.read())

code = re.search(r'window.code = "(.*)";.*window.cssCode',page).group(1)
    print(code)
```

The goal is to backup my files, writing them into files in a clean functional form, the codes can be html+css+js, python, c, etc... I also tried to work on the dirty results with regex modifications, but i think it's impossible, because the codes may contain on purpose elements like "\r\n" that should not be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you got JSON encoded string. You can use `ast.literal_eval()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)) to decode the string:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

url = "https://code.sololearn.com/************/#"
with urlopen(url) as response:
    page = response.read().decode('utf-8')

code = re.search(r'window.code = "(.*)";.*window.cssCode',page, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)

print(literal_eval('"' + code + '"'))
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--
If you're interested in the tools used here:

to display a partition:
http://www.vexflow.com/

to make it sound:
https://tonejs.github.io/
-->
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Annie+Use+Your+Telescope&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tone/13.8.12/Tone.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vexflow/releases/vexflow-min.js"></script>
  <title>Melody Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="popup">
      <div id="description">description gonna be here</div>
      <div id="choice"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="input" class="blur">
      <div id="melody">
        <h1>Melody</h1>
        <textarea id="melo_num" class="text_input" placeholder="Enter two words..."></textarea>
        <p id="melo_rebased"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="rhythm">
        <h1>Rhythm</h1>
        <textarea id="rhyt_num" class="text_input" placeholder="...hear some magic !"></textarea>
        <p id="rhyt_rebased"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="partition" class="blur"></div>
    <div id="controls" class="blur">
      <div id="back" class="control">back</div>
      <div id="play" class="control">play</div>
      <div id="stop" class="control">stop</div>
    </div>
    <div id="current" class="blur"></div>
    <p></p>
    <div id="settings" class="blur">
      <div id="loop" class="blur">loop
        <div class="twinkle lamp" id="loop_lamp"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="root" class="blur">root
        <div class="lamp" id="root_lamp"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="mode" class="blur">mode
        <div class="lamp" id="mode_lamp"></div>
      </div>
            <div id="range" class="blur">range
        <div class="lamp" id="range_lamp"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="rhythm" class="blur">rhythm
        <div class="lamp" id="rhythm_lamp"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="convert" class="blur">convert
        <div class="lamp" id="convert_lamp"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="volume" class="blur slider_box">
        volume
        <input id="sound_vol" class="slider" type="range" min="-50" max="0" value="-10">
      </div>
      <div id="speed" class="blur slider_box">
        speed
        <input id="speed_lvl" class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100">
      </div>
      <div id="sustain" class="blur slider_box">
        sustain
        <input id="sustain_lvl" class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100">
      </div>
      <div id="demo" class="blur">demo
        <div class="lamp" id="demo_lamp"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Or use `json.loads()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.loads)):

```
import json
print(json.loads('"' + code + '"'))
```

Comment: Looks like it's working, only one strange thing, when i use it, unlike the result you're showing, an extra newline is added everytime there's a newline. Any idea why ?

Comment: yep, same with both. And i'm using .decode("utf-8")

Comment: @Cépagrave No idea then, running the code on my computer it prints correctly. Maybe something with terminal settings. Also try to print by lines and use `.strip()` on each line.

Comment: The line by line solution works well ! But oops, i just read scraping is forbidden by terms of use. I will edit and hide the url.